# how to convert the variety customized time stamp to second in hive

Tags: time, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I am looking for a solution for my issue. My issue is I want to convert my data to seconds. The data in my HIVE table looks below:

My input:

```
1 Day 8 Hours 48 Minutes    
1 Hour 1 Minutes    
3 Hours 
20 Minutes
20 Minutes 4 Seconds
50 Seconds
```

My Expected Output in sec

```
118080
3660
10800
1200
1204
50
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can parse all possible templates in a case statement. Maybe this can be optimized, I hope you got the idea. Add more templates and test like this:

```
with mytable as(
select stack(6,
'1 Day 8 Hours 48 Minutes',    
'1 Hour 1 Minutes',   
'3 Hours', 
'20 Minutes',
'20 Minutes 4 Seconds',
'50 Seconds' 
) as mytimestamp 
)


select mytimestamp, ts[0]*86400  --days
                   +ts[1]*3600   --hours
                   +ts[2]*60     --minutes
                   +ts[3]        --seconds 
                   as seconds
from 
(
select mytimestamp, 
       split(
        case when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Days?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$'                            --Days Hours Minutes
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Days?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$','$1:$2:$3:0')

            when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$'                                                     --Hours Minutes
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$','0:$1:$2:0')

            when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)$'                                                                                 --Hours
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Hours?)$','0:$1:0:0')

            when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$'                                                                               --Minutes
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)$','0:0:$1:0')

            when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Seconds?)$'                                                   --Minutes Seconds
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Minutes?)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Seconds?)$','0:0:$1:$2') 

            when mytimestamp rlike '^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Seconds?)$'                                                                               --Seconds
                 then regexp_replace(mytimestamp,'^(\\d{1,2})\\s(?:Seconds?)$','0:0:0:$1')
         end,':') as ts
    from mytable
)s
```

Returns:

```
mytimestamp                seconds  
1 Day 8 Hours 48 Minutes    118080  
1 Hour 1 Minutes            3660    
3 Hours                     10800   
20 Minutes                  1200    
20 Minutes 4 Seconds        1204    
50 Seconds                  50
```